# Calling a function from php in unix cron

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I have a wordpress site.

I have a php file **"test.php"** in the following directory:

```
/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/some_theme/parts/cron
```

The `test.php` has only one function:

```
function cron_test(){
   error_log( print_r( "It works" ) ); //print to debug.log
};
```

**What I want:**

Using `ssh`, `crontab -e`, I want to add a cronjob to call this function.

**What I did:** I tried different sets of cron to see what works or not

```
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/some_theme/parts/cron/test.php -f cron_test> /dev/null 2>&1
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/some_theme/parts/cron/test.php cron_test> /dev/null 2>&1
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/some_theme/parts/cron/test.php > /dev/null 2>&1
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/some_theme/parts/cron/test.php cron_test> /dev/null 2>&1
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/some_theme/parts/cron/test.php -f cron_test> /dev/null 2>&1
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/html/wp-content/themes/some_theme/parts/cron/test.php /dev/null 2>&1
```

Of course, none of them worked.

What am I missing? How would I be able to call this function?

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php pass a variable, check it with switch/if and call the proper method

Comment: Does it need to be a function?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Well, it will be easier to control if it is a function. If there is another way, I am all ears.

Comment: @user1597430 could you be able to give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: This answer may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39008899/5509627

Answer (score 3):

> @user1597430 could you be able to give me an example? Thanks!

Sample call: `php test.php init`

Sample code:

```
<?php

switch ($argv[1])
{
    case 'init':
        cron_test();
}

function cron_test(){
   error_log( print_r( "It works" ) ); //print to debug.log
};
```

Actually, it's a classic way from the C language, you may get more info if you google `argv`/`argc`.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem months ago. To solve it, I created a simple sh script to call my php page, then I call the script into my crontab.

crontab :

```
40 22 * * * sh /.../updateAvai.sh /.../lastUpdateAvai.log
```

updateAvai.sh :

```
#! /bin/bash

php /.../genereListe.php

cat /.../liste | while read LINE
do
php /.../lineTask.php $LINE > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

lineTask.php :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php

<?php

...
// $argv[1] contains the first argument
echo " arg " . $argv[1] . " " . (new \DateTime())->format("Y-m-d H:m:s") . "\n";
...

?>
```

Hope it helps,

Luc.